# Calling update method of polymorphic controller directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery, polymorphism

I'm trying to do an ajax update of a polymorphic model and getting the error:

```
undefined method 'images' for #<Image:0x007fc6517ea378>
app/controllers/images_controller.rb, line 22
```

(It's complaining about the `@imageable.images` of this line `@image = @imageable.images.find(params[:id])`)

This model/controller functions perfectly when CRUDing instances of it from other models but seems to get this error when trying to update it directly.

Why does work when used in a nested form but not when accessed directly?

**image.rb**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('images.id ASC')

  attr_accessible               :asset,
                                :asset_cache, 
                                :active

  belongs_to                    :imageable, polymorphic: true

  mount_uploader                :asset, ImageUploader

  def self.default
    return ImageUploader.new
  end
end
```

**images_controller.rb**

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_imageable
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def new
    @image = @imageable.images.new
  end

  def create
    @image = @imageable.images.new(params[:image])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.save
        format.html { redirect_to @imageable, notice: "Image created." }
      else 
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @image = @imageable.images.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @image.update_attributes(params[:image])
        format.html { redirect_to @imageable, notice: 'Image was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @image = @imageable.images.find(params[:id])
    @image.destroy
  end


  private

  def load_imageable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1, 2]
    @imageable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end
end
```

**ajax call**

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle-image-active", function(event) {
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var currently_active = $(this).attr("data-active");
  var active = true;

  if (currently_active == "true") {
    active = false;
  }

  $.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    dataType: "script",
    url: '/images/' + id,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ resource:{active:active}, _method:'put' })
  }).done(function(msg) {
    console.log( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wasn't understanding and the reason why this wasn't working is because `@imageable` is actually the model that the `image` model belongs to, not the `image` model itself.

As a solution I defined a custom controller action and did a post to it.

```
class ImagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_imageable
  skip_before_filter :load_imageable, :only => :set_active
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def set_active
    Image.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:image])
    render :nothing => true, :status => 200, :content_type => 'text/html'
  end
```

Although this is working, it may not be the best solution so I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I also had to define a custom route `post '/images/set_active/:id' => 'images#set_active'`